# Battle Net Client has 10-15 sec freezes on win7 x64

Tags: performance, response-time

#### problem:

The Battle Net client responds to user input with long freezes (10-15 seconds) when selecting games, etc.

As far as I know, this is only a win7 x64 issue, although this is not confirmed.

#### note:

This is an archive of the solution that was posted a few years ago on Reddit.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Blizzard/comments/7kol9s/battlenet_app_keeps_freezing/

The Blizzard forums stopped supporting the old links and every discussion about the topic led to this post describing the solution, that is sadly no longer available:
https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20753715303#post-4

I've added the solution on StackOverflow to keep the sacred knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

#### solution:

go to: *Start Menu* -> *Edit Group Policy*

this opens the **Local Group Policy Editor**

go to *User Configuration/Windows Settings/Internet Explorer Maintenance/Connection/Automatic Browser Configuration*

Uncheck the "automatically detect configuration settings" checkbox

The Battle Net client should now respond quickly to user inputs.